# Identifying an inductor

Tags: identification, inductor, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a circuit here.  I have almost all of the items identified, down to their specifications, except two inductors

I'm not very familiar with inductors, so I figured I'd ask for some help.

[image: The two inductors]

Besides the value (100uH) and tolerance (10%), are there any other things I should be concerned about?  The voltage being handled by the circuit is 14-18v

Here is where they are in the circuit (cheap Visio drawing of the circuit in question:

[image: Location of the inductors]

Comment: What is their purpose in this circuit?

Comment: Added a circuit diagram

Answer (score 2):

> Besides the value (100uH) and tolerance (10%), are there any other things I should be concerned about?

Max current and power is a big thing to worry about, if you replace the inductor with a different one that can't handle the max current or power you could potentially burn it out. Additionally DCR or DC resistance is also important for max power considerations and voltage drop.

Sometimes it can be important to characterize the inductors entire impedance for some applications:
You can do that with this link
https://www.dos4ever.com/inductor/inductor.html

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these used to filter power supply lines. ( stopping high frequency noise from coming in or going out). They are low current ( like 100ma) chokes.

Comment: I just added a circuit diagram.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: From your diagram they are being used  to filter the PWM signal, and also probably to reduce the brush noise of the motor. As voltage spike said, it looks like you need to ensure these chokes can handle the motor current ( ten times what I guessed  they can handle) .